# How to find out what type a JsonValue is in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json

So when I have a JsonNode I can just ask if it's a JsonObject or a JsonArray and work with those. But when the node is an actual value, how do I know whether it's a string, number or boolean?

Of course I could just try and parse the value, but then a number transmitted in a string would become a number instead of a string which I'd like to avoid.

I'm using System.Text.Json with .NET 6.

Comment: Don't the regular C# type checks work? `if(someValue is string)`..?

Comment: Tried it an, interestingly, the error says `An expression of type System.Text.Json.JsonNode? cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'string'`. Not what I expected and not sure what it means exactly, thought a type check would always be possible. Edit: Same for other primitive type checks.

Comment: From [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueOfT.cs), it looks like a `JsonValue` just wraps a `JsonElement`. So you might be able to do `.GetValue<JsonElement>()` (which passes [this check](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueOfT.cs,39)), and the inspect its [`ValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonelement-valuekind) property?

Comment: Yess this one works, thank you very much!

Comment: @canton7 Put that in an answer then I can checkmark it :)

Comment: `JsonNodeExtensions.GetValueKind(this JsonNode node, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)` from [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55827#issuecomment-889443545) by [steveharter](https://github.com/steveharter) to [JsonNode feedback #55827](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55827) seems to do what you need.  (Be sure to click on *`click for samples`* to see the code.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueOfT.cs), it looks like a `JsonValue` just wraps a `JsonElement`. So you can do `.GetValue<JsonElement>()` (which passes [this check](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueOfT.cs,39)), and then inspect its [`ValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonelement-valuekind) property.

Comment: The [source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueOfT.cs,36) also shows that the underlying value may not be a `JsonElement`.

Comment: "A value of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to a 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement'."

Comment: This does not work. I get the same error as SerG

Comment: You could just use TryGetValue
someObject["SomeNode"].AsValue().TryGetValue<someType>(out someType result)

Comment: `JsonNodeExtensions.GetValueKind(this JsonNode node, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)` from [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55827#issuecomment-889443545) by [steveharter](https://github.com/steveharter) to [JsonNode feedback #55827](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55827) handles both the `JsonElement` and non-`JsonElement` cases.  (Be sure to click on *`click for samples`* to see the code.)

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer only works for specific use cases, namely that the node in question is of type JsonValue.

I propose a better option is to first test for the basic kind of types there are in JSON.

```cs
someObject["SomeNode"] is JsonArray 
someObject["SomeNode"] is JsonObject
someObject["SomeNode"] is JsonValue
```

if the object is of type JsonValue one can use tryGetvalue to directly test for the expected value type

```cs
someObject["SomeNode"].AsValue().TryGetValue<someType>(out someType result)
```

TryGetValue returns true if it the value was parseble as the requested type.

If the expected type is completely unknown or variable (ugh), you could use the

```cs
someObject["SomeNode"].GetValue<JsonElement>().ValueKind
```

trick. But that only works for distinquishing between int and string and the bool values. Trying this on an array will give an exception. Therefore you first have to test with the "is" style syntax above.

Comment: As you can see in the first paragraph of the question, something being a JsonObject or JsonArray is already being checked and the question itself is specifically about what to do when it's in fact a JsonValue. Thanks for the complete answer though, might be helpful to people coming through search engines in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The following code works in .NET fiddle with .NET 6.

Note:

- if your `JsonValue` ultimately came from a `JsonNode.Parse*(...)`, then your `JsonValue` will contain a "JSON type".
- if your `JsonValue` was created using `JsonValue.Create()` or an implicit conversion, then your `JsonValue` will contain a "CLR type".
- The following code returns an approximate "CLR type" for "JSON types", because of the next point.
- `JsonValue.GetValue<T>()` only does type conversion if `JsonValue` contains a "JSON type".
- `JsonValue.GetValue<object>()` conveniently returns the underlying value, which is a `JsonElement` if it is a "JSON type".

```
public static class JsonValueExtensions
{
    public static Type GetValueType(this JsonValue jsonValue)
    {
        var value = jsonValue.GetValue<object>();
        if (value is JsonElement element)
        {
            return element.ValueKind switch
            {
                JsonValueKind.False => typeof(bool),
                JsonValueKind.True => typeof(bool),
                JsonValueKind.Number => typeof(double),
                JsonValueKind.String => typeof(string),
                var _ => typeof(JsonElement),
            };
        }
        return value.GetType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each JsonProperty has two properties - Name and Value of Type JsonElement. JsonElement has an Enum property named [ValueKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonvaluekind?view=net-6.0) which can help you determine what of what data type your JSON value is.

You can get JsonProperties by calling .EnumerateObject() on your JsonElement. You can work with your Json document as a JsonElement instead of JsonObject.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of JsonElement  returned you have to handle it differently.

My case was that the returned element was ValueKind = Array : "[[47.751]]"
So in order to get it I did created this method

```
private object GetValueFromJsonElement(WorkbookRange range)
{
    var element = range.Values.RootElement.EnumerateArray().First()[0];
    switch (element.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Number:
            return element.GetDouble();

        case JsonValueKind.String:
            return element.GetString();

        case JsonValueKind.True:
        case JsonValueKind.False:
            return element.GetBoolean();
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The Value Type returned is not handled");
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is talking about a JsonObject not a JsonElement...

Comment: @DouglasGaskell If you take a look at the accepted answer, in the source link, you'll see that I'm not so far off topic.